# Cloudfront, stale-while-revalidate and invalidations - serve stale while refreshing cache?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

We have some requests setup with:

```
max-age=1800, public, s-maxage=3600, stale-if-error=3600, stale-while-revalidate=600
```

However there are cases where a URL may be invalidated by the backend during a content update, for example.

While load testing this, I can see that when the invalidation happens the CDN lets through many concurrent requests until it has received a response.

I was under the impression that `stale-while-revalidate` should cause the CDN to continue to serve the previous content until it had fetched new data?

Is there a way to "soft-purge", maybe?

Does SWR only apply for when the max-age has expired?

EDIT:

Clarification; my expectation/hope was that the CDN would receive the invalidation and on the next request would fetch from the origin while serving stale. While the origin is responding, the CDN responds with stale content. Subsequently, after a good response, the CDN would start serving the new content.

What I am actually seeing is that the invalidation kicks in and then next request is a cache "miss" and the response is effectively from the origin (ie much slower than the CDN). What is worse is that Cloudfront is letting traffic stamped the origin during this period while the cache is waiting for a response to cache, even with Origin Shield enabled.

Comment: It's not clear to me how what you're seeing is different from what you're expecting, or what you mean by soft-purge. By "lets through" do you mean that the CDN is not serving its stale cached response? Could you clarify exactly what behavior you'd like to see in the CDN?

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry - I have updated the question. Thanks for responding.

Comment: I don't see any documentation on this, but perhaps CloudFront considers an invalidation as too severe to allow serving stale content, regardless of the headers. (The documentation does refer to "removing" a file on invalidation, rather than simply marking as stale, in which case there would be nothing to serve.) Note that invalidation is a CloudFront thing, it's not part of the HTTP specification that governs the semantics of the `CacheControl` header.